# Android studio build error UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Getting this error whenever I build:

```
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unresolved local class: com/toppr/dubbio/v3/base/BaseSocketActivity$serviceConnection$1
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$classes$1.invoke(NotFoundClasses.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$classes$1.invoke(NotFoundClasses.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:483)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.NotFoundClasses.getClass(NotFoundClasses.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer$typeConstructor$1.invoke(TypeDeserializer.kt:120)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.typeConstructor(TypeDeserializer.kt:124)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.simpleType(TypeDeserializer.kt:82)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.type(TypeDeserializer.kt:70)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.type$default(TypeDeserializer.kt:62)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.MemberDeserializer.loadProperty(MemberDeserializer.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeProperties(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:123)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.access$computeProperties(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$properties$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$properties$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:483)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.getContributedVariables(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedVariables(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:232)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.addFunctionsAndProperties(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:185)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeDescriptors(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:153)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:218)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:211)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:370)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:223)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedDescriptors$default(ResolutionScope.kt:40)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope$_allDescriptors$2.invoke(SubstitutingScope.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope$_allDescriptors$2.invoke(SubstitutingScope.kt:30)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope.get_allDescriptors(SubstitutingScope.kt)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope.getContributedDescriptors(SubstitutingScope.kt:80)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedDescriptors$default(ResolutionScope.kt:40)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.computeExtraDescriptors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:71)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$extraDescriptors$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:58)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$extraDescriptors$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:47)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:370)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:64)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorUtils.getAllDescriptors(DescriptorUtils.java:578)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.resolveMemberHeaders(LazyClassDescriptor.java:569)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.doForceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:539)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.lambda$new$4(LazyClassDescriptor.java:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.forceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:535)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:75)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:41)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:66)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:34)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:119)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:133)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doAnalysis(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.doAnalysis(Kapt3Extension.kt:145)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:104)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:376)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:367)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:132)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:158)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:353)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:86)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:213)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:83)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:515)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:399)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:892)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:891)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:398)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[KOTLIN] deleting /Users/mayankgupta/StudioProjects/toppr-android-chat/app/build/tmp/kapt3/incrementalData/debug on error
[KOTLIN] deleting /Users/mayankgupta/StudioProjects/toppr-android-chat/app/build/tmp/kapt3/incrementalData/debug on error

After clean and then building, it works fine. First build try always throws this error

Comment: Looks like you have found a bug.

Comment: what should i do? What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Search if there is already a bug report (maybe it contains a workaround). Otherwise make a bug report and wait until it gets fixed.

Comment: I have the same issue.....first build is is always failed.

Comment: Same error here, it fails the first time then the second build works. When changing code and rebuild, the first build fails again then the next succeed

Comment: I have the similar issue here, first build is is always failed.

Comment: I reported a bug in issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78901746
If everyone have similar issue, please leave message on it, thanks.